# Non-Flask Frontend with Flask Backend Confusion

Tags: api, flask, google-api

all,

I need a little bit of guidance here. I have a Polymer frontend that handles Google oAuth to allow the user in the app. The front end captures the user's email address from oAuth and uses that for GET requests to a Flask API that I built on the backend. I did not build authentication into my Flask API because I didn't think I needed to since I have Polymer as the gatekeeper. I realized though that folks can see the source code and retried the API URL to use if they wanted to capture other user's data.

I am looking for guidance on how I can lock down the API backend given I am only using Google oAuth on the front end.

Thank you,

Marcos

Comment: Have you hard-coded a very sensitive URL that is absolutely required for your application to communicate with Google OAuth?

Comment: Not for Google oAuth on the client side, but my server side API does not use Google oAuth. How do I best protect the server side API given my front end setup?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct answer, but I will post my result anyway. If wrong, send feedback. I am going to have my frontend send the user's access token from the auth process in the header with every API call. My backend API will take that access token and use it to query the Google API to find what email address the token was created by. If the email matches the email the API call is requesting data for, data will be returned. If not, it will return an error.